# How to build a query in SQL Server to find occurrences of text after finding initial text?

Tags: sql-server, regex

In SQL Server, I have a table with free text column and am trying to find 2 patterns inside of it. The first pattern will be a keyword of sorts, say "SSN", and the next pattern will be the number "123456789" AFTER the pattern SSN has been found.

I'm trying to find the rows of data where I find the keyword "SSN" and the SSN number somewhere to the right of the found keyword (could be a " ", : , >, =, " "=" ", " is ", etc. separating the keyword from the actual number).

The data in the column is something like this:

```
ID     myColumn
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1      Customer's account number is 098765432 and their SSN = 123456789
2      Move account 763894571 to 918384567 because the SSN has been updated
```

I've searched around and really can't find what I'm looking for and was hoping someone here can help out.

I've used the following query:

```sql
SELECT ID, myColumn 
FROM myTable 
WHERE myColumn LIKE '% SSN%' 
  AND (myColumn LIKE '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%')
```

My goal is to only see ID 1 data, because ID 2 does not have SSN followed by the 9 digit number; but it shows both rows. How can I just pull the data I'm looking for?

Comment: Storing people's SSN in clear text like this is borderline criminal behavior. That kind of data should be encrypted when at rest.

Answer (score 2):

Use LIKE only once for both conditions:

```
SELECT ID, myColumn 
FROM myTable 
WHERE myColumn like '% SSN%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c067508863eb9366f47f1a04311e3170).
Result:

```
> ID | myColumn                                                        
> -: | :---------------------------------------------------------------
>  1 | Customer's account number is 098765432 and their SSN = 123456789
```

Comment: True, nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to only see ID 1 data, because ID 2 does not have SSN
>   followed by the 9 digit number; but it shows both rows. How can I just
>   pull the data I'm looking for?

You can use [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), which returns the character position where a certain pattern begins in a string.

So for instance, you could use PATINDEX('%SSN%', MyColumn) to get the character position where 'SSN' can be found in the column.

AND you can also use it to see if there is a 9-number pattern in the string with a PATINDEX that is HIGHER than the PATINDEX of 'SSN'.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help...

```
SELECT ID, myColumn,  SUBSTRING(myColumn,CHARINDEX('SSN',myColumn,10), LEN(myColumn) ) 
from myTable WHERE
myColumn like '% SSN%' 
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myTable t where t.id = mytable.id 
and SUBSTRING(myColumn,CHARINDEX('SSN',myColumn,10), LEN(myColumn) )  like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%')
```